# Powershell-registered Managed Accounts not showing up in Central Admin

Tags: 2010, powershell, central-administration

I'm trying to set up a work laptop for SharePoint development.  To get it up and running quickly, I used my corporate domain user account as the first managed account.  Now, I want to use a local account (as I don't have permissions to create domain accounts) for the managed account and service accounts.

Using [this](http://www.theodells.org/theodells/blog/2010/09/using-local-managed-accounts-in-sharepoint-2010/) link and [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863%28v=office.14%29.aspx) link, I successfully registered the local account as a managed service account in powershell and registered the app pool to run under the local account for both CA and IIS.  However, now I am trying to migrate the SharePoint service accounts to use the local managed service account and I'm not having great luck.

The local account shows in CA through `Security`>`Configure managed accounts` but when I go to `Security`>`Configure service accounts`, the local account does not show up in any of the drop downs for any service accounts.

While I am curious as to exactly why it doesn't show up, I would also be happy if I knew how to move these service accounts from my corporate account to my local account.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Powershell to set up the managed account using [PSCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscredential(v=vs.85).aspx) and [New-SPManagedAccount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607831.aspx). There is [an example](https://www.windegger.wtf/sharepoint-2013-managed-accounts-2/) I've wrote some time ago that is used to create the managed accounts based on an input file. When I'm right the netBiosDomain should be your local computer or ".".